# how to create regions on zen

Tags: theming, 7

I would create regions on my zen theme, reflecting the narrow columns side by side.

I want a layout that does not provide the content by default, but it plans to create 3 sidebar facing the same width.How can I do?

EDIT

Also, I want the page layout different from the initial layout of other pages, so I can have different layout templates with different regions?

Comment: Sounds like you would be better helped by searching for information about basic HTML/CSS layout structures rather than Drupal theming.

Answer (score 3):

In the file your_theme.info you should add

```
regions[new_region] = New Region
```

regions[new_region] this is the machine name so the variable will be $new_region

Then on page.tpl.php you should add the html and the php like

```
<?php
if ($new_region) :?>
<div id="new-region">
<?php print $new_region; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Remember to flush the cache and do the performance after you modify page.tpl.php

Comment: but how it is determined the position of the region added?

Comment: May you be more clear? If you are asking me in which place it is going to be shown, the answer is, it depend where you put your HTML/PHP. page.tpl.php is a php page with html structure. Is this you doubt?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a region on my Zen 7.x-5.5 subtheme like this:

1. Added: `regions[new_region] = New Region` to my_theme.info
2. Added (*differs slightly from Tyler Durden's code which haven't worked for me*):

`<?php if ($page['new_region']) :?>
        <div id="new_region">
        <?php print render($page['new_region']); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>`

to page.tpl.php.

3. Cleared the cashe.